# How to ignore collation when comparing Á to a

Tags: utf-8, amazon-redshift

I'm working on a migration of a SQL from mysql to redshift. One of the columns is a utf8 characters (not mb4). For simplicity the SQL looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN b
  ON a.name = b.name;
```

The table's data looks like:

`a`:

| Name |
| --- |
| a |

`b`:

| Name |
| --- |
| Á |

With the given data and SQL above, in MySQL the SQL will return one row. Where redshift will not. I was trying to do `collate(a.name,'case_insensitive') = collate(b.name,'case_insensitive')` but it made no difference.

Really hope anyone have an advice for me how I can make this same behavior as MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find builtin solution, so I made one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unaccent_string(text)
RETURNS text
IMMUTABLE
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT translate(
    $1,
    'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿĀāĂăĄąĆćĈĉĊċČčĎďĐđĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĲĳĴĵĶķĸĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłŃńŅņŇňŉŊŋŌōŎŏŐőŒœŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞşŠšŢţŤťŦŧŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵŶŷŸŹźŻżŽžſ',
    'AAAAAAACEEEEIIIIENOOOOOOUUUUYPsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiienoooooouuuuypyAaAaAaCcCcCcCcDdDdEeEeEeEeEeGgGgGgGgHhHhIiIiIiIiIiIiJjKkkLlLlLlLlLlNnNnNnnNnOoOoOoOoRrRrRRSsSsSsSsTtTtTtUuUuUuUuUuUuWwYyYZzZzZzs'
);
$$;
```

Then I could do:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN b
  ON upper(unaccent_string(a.name)) = upper(unaccent_string(b.name));
```

Comment: Yes, a UDF is a common approach but can have performance implications when run on large datasets.  If this is the case you will want to add the translate() function to the query directly. (CTEs can help readability)  You basically have a data quality issue (same information represented differently) and ascii_name as a column to your tables where this info is prepopulated.